# Why are there four graves when Ciel first comes home?

Tags: black-butler

[image: four graves]

Spoilers below for those who haven't read **Chapter 129**.

When Ciel first comes home with Sebastian,

> why are there 4 graves when only 3 people died (Vincent, Rachel, and Real!Ciel)?

So why would there be four? Could it be that they're pre-made? Or maybe they assumed that

> Our!Ciel is already dead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth grave is Our!Ciel’s grave. They made graves for the four of them since they assumed they all died in the fire.